# Manually specifying colours for overlayed plots created from the same data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working with a dataset that contains two groups within the column `youngOld`: `young` and `old`. I have created a scatterplot with the actual values and line plots with the values predicted by a model.

```
set.seed(123)
df2 <- data.frame(
  time = rep(1:10, 2),
  value = c(runif(10), runif(10) + 1),
  predicted_value = c(runif(10), runif(10) + 1.5),
  youngOld = rep(c("young", "old"), each = 10)
)

sample <- ggplot(df2, aes(x = time, y = value)) + 
  geom_point(aes(col = youngOld), show.legend = TRUE) +
  geom_line(aes(y = predicted_value, col = youngOld), show.legend = TRUE) +
  labs(title = "Scatterplot",
       x = "time",
       y = "value")
sample
```

In reality, my plots contain many datapoints, so I would like to specify that the lines should be in different colours than the dotplots, as they won't be visible otherwise. How do I do this ?  (I haven't found any questions that address this, but apologies if they exist)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be the `ggnewscale` package which allows for multiple scales (and/or legends) for the same aesthetic. This way you can easily apply a different color scale for your line plot:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

ggplot(df2, aes(x = time, y = value)) +
  geom_point(aes(col = youngOld)) +
  ggnewscale::new_scale_color() +
  geom_line(aes(y = predicted_value, col = youngOld)) +
  scale_color_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set1") +
  labs(
    title = "Scatterplot",
    x = "time",
    y = "value"
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In addition to stefan answer.

If you want to manually select colors in the same tone, you can play with alpha values of lines and dots (high alpha values for lines, low alpha values for dots).

With a lot of dots, it should discriminate lines from dots.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

ggplot(df2, aes(x = time, y = value)) +
  geom_point(aes(col = youngOld), alpha=0.3) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#01957c", "#952301")) +
  ggnewscale::new_scale_color() +
  geom_line(aes(y = predicted_value, col = youngOld), alpha=1) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#01957c", "#952301")) +
  labs(
    title = "Scatterplot",
    x = "time",
    y = "value"
  )
```

[image]